# how to make pop up overlay with my screen using java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Im trying to make a java program that will popup/notify me to stop what I am currently doing and do something. more like a reminder. My question is how will I make a pop up in java.

I found this docs, but dont know how to implement for the parent component.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(??,"this is a modal dialog.");
```

Comment: You can pass it `null` if you have no other component/window.  It's allows the `JOptionPane` to present a modal dialog which must be dismissed before you can interact with the parent component/window, but can be `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends, do you have a parent component (like a `JFrame` or other component) or are you simply display the `JOptionPane` independently?

If you are simply displaying the `JOptionPane` independently, you can simply pass it `null`.

If you are displaying the `JOptionPane` as part of a large application, with windows and other components, you can simply pass it a reference of what ever component you want the `JOptionPane` to displayed relative to, such as the window or most accessible container/component

The `parent` argument (if supplied) simply allows the dialog to act as a modal (blocking) dialog for the window which contains the supplied component.  This requires the user to have to dismiss the dialog before they can continue to interact with the parent window/component

Take a closer look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details